# How to append to a file without duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read from a file and append a line to the file only if the line didn't occur in the file. My code is

```
forwhom=msg.split("for ",1)[1]
f = open("itsover.txt","r")
fl = f.readlines()
f.close()
fl.append(forwhom)
flset = list(set(fl))
f = open("itsover.txt","w")
for line in flset:
    line=line.strip()
    f.write(line+"\n")
    print(line)
f.close()
```

but the set part doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: What is `forwhom` in your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Please give us the specific example: include the data set and failing output.  I suspect it's merely a matter of whether the newline is handled properly.

Comment: If `forwhom` includes lines (without the newline character) that exist in the file, that's your problem. Since they don't include the newline character, they aren't the same and therefore aren't removed in the set.

Comment: Think about why you added `line = line.strip()` to your code and how it affects the set operation if it's done after or before it.

Comment: @Bazingaa `forwhom` is a string which I want to append if it didn't occur there before

Comment: @zondo oh, that makes sense. Thanks, I'll see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any file, I created one sample `file.txt` which contains

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 2
Line 4
Line 4
```

Then I define a string `forwhom = 'Line 2\n'` with a newline character `\n`. A slight modification in your code and it does what you want. The output file is named `itsover.txt`. I decided to chose a different name for the output file.

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
fl = f.readlines()
f.close()

forwhom = 'Line 2\n'
fl.append(forwhom)
flset = list(set(fl))

f = open("itsover.txt","w")
for line in flset:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

The output file contains:

```
Line 4
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

You can use some sorting algorithm to make sure the order of lines in the input and output file stays the same. But I guess it answers your question. The problem was, as someone pointed out in the comments, the missing `\n` character in `forwhom`. In the above code, if you replace `forwhom = 'Line 2\n'` by `forwhom = 'Line 2'`, you will see that the output will not be as expected.

Comment: Adding `+ "\n"` to forwhom fixed my problem, thank you!

Comment: if u doing readlines() just check  if str in f.readlines():

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with working on appending data as comma separated values to text files [usually within a for loop] the following syntax seemed to be working just fine. You might wanna check it out. (Not using set btw)

```
# open your file before the loop
with open("your text file", "r+") as f:
    for i in <your list>:
        # store values in a variable
        value = str(i) + ", " + str(x) + ", " + ...
        # append to your file without duplicates
        for line in f:
            if str(i) in line.rstrip('\r\n'):
               print("exists")
               break
        # note that else is outside the for loop
        else:
            print("Appending New Value ...")
            f.write(str(value) + "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

first read all text. check if modification is needed and append if so.

```
path='/path/to/file'
content = open(path, 'r').read()
to_add='foo'
if to_add not in content:
    with open(path, 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(to_add)
```

Comment: The two ```open```s will probably clash this way, I suggest using a ```with``` for the first one too.

Comment: agree with @tevemadar

Answer (score -1):

A workaround that worked for me

```
data="Hey"
try:
    if data not in open("toadd.txt").read():
        with open("toadd.txt","a") as outfile:
            outfile.write(data+"\n") #if you want to add a new line
except IOError: #if the file doesn't exist create a new one
    with open("toadd.txt","a") as outfile:
        outfile.write(data+"\n") #if you want to add a new line
```